# How to increment a variable when condition is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I wish to increment variables if a condition is true.

I have a object that has info like

```
{id: 1, payment: pending}
{id: 2, payment: paid}
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
  $scope.unpaid = 0;
  $scope.paid = 0;

  const getSessions = () => {
    loginService.getUser().then((response) => {
      var user_id = response.data.id;
      console.log("getUser returning this => ", response.data);
      loginService.getUserSessions(user_id).then((response) => {
        var sessions = response.data;
        console.log(sessions);
        sessions.forEach(e => e.next_class = e.next_class.substring(0, 10));
        sessions.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
          if(arrayItem.payment === "Pending") {
            $scope.unpaid++;
          }else{
            $scope.paid++;
          };
      });
        $scope.new = sessions;
       Date($scope.class).toISOString().slice(0,10);
      })
    })
  };

  getSessions();
```

I can loop in the object using the `for each`, but I want to loop through the object and check the `payment` key. If `payment == pending` store in `unpaid`, and if `payment == paid` then store in `paid`.

The front end would show how many unpaid sessions and paid there are displayed in numbers, for example:

```
Unpaid 1

Paid 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the objects are in an array, I'll also assume it is called `payments`:

```
var paid = 0;
var unpaid = 0;

var payments = [{id: 1, payment: 'paid'}, {id: 2, payment: 'unpaid'}, {id: 3, payment: 'unpaid'}];

for (var payment in payments) { // iterate through all payments
    if (payments[payment].payment == 'paid') { // if the person has paid
        paid++; // count a payment
    } else { // if the person hasn't paid
        unpaid++; // count a non-payment
    }
}

console.log("Paid: " + paid + ", Unpaid: " + unpaid);
```

Also, you should probably make `payment` a boolean, and call it `paid`, where true means the person has paid, false means not paid. 
If you do that, then you can change the if condition to say `if (payments[payment].paid) { ... }`. Much nicer!

Comment: Edited my example, you can run that sample and let me know if it makes sense!

Comment: So it does work but for some reason when I delete a session it still increments the unpaid variable. Should decrease

Comment: If you delete a session and want the paid and unpaid variables to be updated, you need to reset them to 0 and run the same process again. This code will not update on its own.